# django getting data and routing in view.py

Tags: django, openlayers

in my project i have 3 action for users , my quest. is how can i route them

my code:

```
def featuresave(request):
 layerId = request.POST.get("layid")
 features = request.POST.get("feat")

 if features == 'POINT': #( it includes Point string and coordinate as "POINT(38 39)"    
   als = Point()
   als.layer = Layers.objects.get(id = layerId)
   als.feature = features
   als.save()

 if feature == 'LINESTRING': #( it includes Linestring string and coordinate )
   als = Line()
   als.layer = Layers.objects.get(id = layerId)
   als.feature = feature
   als.save()

 if feature == 'POLYGON': #( it includes Linestring string and coordinate )
   als = Poly()
   als.layer = Layers.objects.get(id = layerId)
   als.feature = feature
   als.save()

return HttpResponse("OK")
```

thanks for your help

Comment: is there a problem with your code right now ? (minus the pseudocode)

Comment: note you do features=request.POST and you compare 'feature' in your second and third tests. Is this the problem? You haven't been clear. Always cut and paste your code to avoid typos in transcriptions.

Comment: it not save linestring in Line model via database

Comment: i didnt find any solution when i did as  als = Point()
   als.layer = Layers.objects.get(id = layerId)
   als.feature = features
   als.save()
it saves..... but when i do  if features == 'POINT': etc it not save in database because post data not include this

Comment: Well there's your problem. That's an HTML issue. You have to POST something with the key `feat` for features not to be `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comments, and assuming you are talking about what your request.POST.feat includes:

```
 #( it includes Point string and coordinate as "POINT(38 39)" 
 #( it includes Linestring string and coordinate )
 #( it includes Linestring string and coordinate )
```

and the comparisons before the comments... you aren't going to get a match...

Your comparisons should probably be something like

```
if feature.find('POINT') != -1:
    #do something
elif feature.find('LINESTRING') != -1:
    #do something
elif feature.find('POLYGON') != -1:
    #do something
```